# Init method inheritance

Tags: kotlin

If I have abstract class A with an init method:

```
abstract class A(){
  init {
    println("Hello")
  }     
}
```

And then class B that extends A

```
class B(): A()
```

If I instantiate B like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
  B()
}
```

Does the init method in A still get run and `Hello` gets printed?

And if not, what do I need to do to have the init method of A get run?

Comment: This question basically asks how a particular piece of code runs. Wouldn't it be more productive to just check the result in a sand box? http://try.kotlinlang.org/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, an `init` block of a base class gets run when the derived class instance is initialized.

In Kotlin, similarly to Java, an instance of a class is constructed in the following way:

1. An object is allocated.
2. The constructor of the class is called. *(a)*

   1. If the class has a superclass, **the superclass constructor is called before the class construction logic is executed**; 
      <sup>(i.e., the point *(a)* is executed recursively for the superclass, then the execution continues from here)</sup>
   2. If the class has property initializers or `init` blocks, they are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body;
   3. If the constructor has a body (i.e. it is a [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)) then the body is executed.

In this description, you can see that, when `B` is constructed, the constructor of `A` is called before `B` initialization logic is executed, and, in particular, all `init` blocks of `A` are executed.

<sup>[(runnable demo of this logic)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/dark2jd0kp97m52f2kpn3426ej/1n0qfonaeh6825mfaepeipjvvv)</sup>

---

A small remark on terminology: `init` block is not actually a separate method. Instead, all `init` blocks together with member property initializers are compiled into the code of the constructor, so they should rather be considered a part of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the demo!

Comment: I wanna add such demos to my answers too!

Comment: @DmitryGryazin, consider using https://play.kotl.in, this is a more recent playground than https://try.kotl.in.

Comment: Is it possible to initialize the class before the superclass?

Comment: @Doruko, no, you can't do this with inheritance because the ordering of constructor invocations is enforced by the virtual machine (in case of the JVM) and the compiler (in case of the other platforms). If you need to run some logic before initialization logic of the other class, you should probably prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: @hotkey the problem is that the superclass' constuctor is calling a function that needs a variable from the class (which is unitialized yet), is there a way to solve this?

Comment: If you control the superclass, you can pass the value of the variable to the constructor of the superclass. Otherwise, I doubt there is an elegant way.