# Passing 'this' to a Constructor

Tags: constructor, jvm, kotlin, this

Say I have `open class C(val c:C)` and I want to subclass it as `class D():C(this)`

This is invalid according to the compiler because `'this' is not defined in this context`

Is there a way to get this to do what I want? Specifically, I'd like for `D` to have a constructor that can be called without any arguments and will pass the `D` object being constructed to `C`'s constructor. In my case, it's fine that this object may not be fully constructed yet.

I'm open to any solutions that don't involve changing `C`, reflection included.

Comment: The JVM’s verifier is mandated to reject any code that attempts to use an `<uninitialized this>` (the `this` reference before the super class constructor has been called) where an initialized instance is required (like a constructor’s parameter). Without changing `C`, there can’t be a language solution… Or well, it depends on *why* you need this or what the `C`’s constructor is supposed to do with that `C` reference…

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'd gladly accept it as an answer if this is really the case. For me, `C`'s constructor only stores the reference for later use after construction, so I was hoping it could be done, but the fact that it can't is a useful answer in itself.

Comment: Since you said, “reflection included”, you could overwrite the field *after* the superconstructor returned. Access override includes the possibility to overwrite `final` instance fields. You only have to pass a dummy value to the superclass constructor first, if it doesn’t allow `null`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no straightforward solution, because it does not seem to be a good idea.

The constructor of the super class gets executed before the constructor of the class itself does ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766613/2196460)). Thus passing `this` instance that has not been initialized at all to the super constructor in place of a valid instance may break some of the logic of the super constructor (e.g. it may expect the `c`'s properties to have some meaningful values, but they don't).

If you need this so bad, you can try to create an instance of `D` first with some fake/default `C`, then create another `D` with the first one:

```
class D(c: C) : C(c)

fun createD(defaultC: C): D {
    val firstD = D(defaultC)
    return D(firstD)
}
```

Though this definitely does not cover all possible use cases.