# How can I ensure that a Kotlin child class is finished initializing?

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance, initialization

When it comes to the order of `init` method calls in Kotlin, there is a strange side-effect that I would like to try and avoid. Here is the current situation:

```
interface ExcitingInitialize {
    fun excitingInit()
}

abstract class Parent: ExcitingInitialize {
    
    init {
        excitingInit()
    }    
}

class Child: Parent() {
    
    val myName: String = "Child"
    
   
    override fun excitingInit() {
        println("${myName} initialized.")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val p1 = Child()    // Outputs "null initialized"
    p1.excitingInit()   // Outputs "Child initialized" 
}
```

My goal is to avoid "null initialized", so I want to "wait" until `Child` is ready before parent calls `excitingInit()`.

I know *why* this happens - the problem is that while `init` does trigger the child class's `excitingInit()` method, it does so before the `init` of the child class has executed. Thus `myName` is not yet available.

The question is what can I do to ensure that I call `excitingInit()` only after Child's `init` has completed - and to do this without requiring `Child` to implement any `init` or `constructor` of its own (I want the user of my parent class to not have to worry about calling special init methods).

For reference, [this works just fine in Swift](https://swiftfiddle.com/o6wwmjeysvd5fmpdakfoqfenae) - I am trying to achieve something similar in Kotlin.

Comment: IMO, Swift has got the initialisation order right. Java didn't, and as a result Kotlin must follow the same order because it's designed to work well with Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Init method inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766441/init-method-inheritance)

Comment: @Crebain That does answer _why_ but I am interested in how to work around this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

0. Use an explicit [secondary `constructor`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#secondary-constructors) in the parent class:

   > the code in all initializer blocks and property initializers is executed before the body of the secondary constructor.
1. Replace `myName` with a method `getMyName()` returning a constant.
2. Create a constructor method *on the parent class* that must be called after the object is created.
3. Drop the parent class and make a factory function `createNewChild` that calls `excitingInit` or whatever is necessary.
4. While you might not like it, an explicit `init` or `constructor` in the child class is also an option.

Comment: I went for option 4 - this seems to be the least problematic and most easily enforceable.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for this kind of situation, you could try to use [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables).
So, your code could look like [this](https://pl.kotl.in/orWTZa5qY):

```kotlin
interface ExcitingInitialize {
    fun excitingInit()
}

abstract class Parent: ExcitingInitialize {
    
    init {
        excitingInit()
    }    
}

class Child: Parent() {
    lateinit var myName: String
    
   
    override fun excitingInit() {
        if (!this::myName.isInitialized) {
          myName = "Child"
        }
        println("${myName} initialized.")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val p1 = Child()    // Outputs "Child initialized"
    p1.excitingInit()   // Outputs "Child initialized" 
}
```

So, your field initializes directly in the parent.